# TENSE of subordinate clause

Tags: tense

I wondered which of the following is right:

1. Will you briefly email me what the session **is** like after each of the coming sessions?
2. Will you briefly email me what the session **was** like after each of the coming sessions?
3. Will you briefly email me what the session **will have been** like after each of the coming sessions?

Comment: It's the second one. The person is asked to report what the session which has just finished _was_ like.

Comment: "after each one" is enough, you don't need: of the coming sessions. :)

Comment: Will you (kindly) send me a brief email account of each session.

Comment: I've closed this question to new answers for two reasons: 1. it's a request for proofreading, which is off-topic on this site; and 2. you need to tell us what you already know about those tenses. It's beyond the scope of this website to explain the differences among those three tenses. Please edit your question to include what you already know about the tenses, why you think they might each be correct, and what you're confused about

Comment: You might use "is like" with an unchanging thing, while "was like" means what it was like at the time. "After the class let me know what the venue is like" - "It is a nice building" - all present tense. But "After the class let me know what that week's class was like" - "The class was very hard." - past tense for a one-off event.

Answer (score 1):

No. 3 isn't right at all. "Will have been" is in the future perfect tense, which refers to actions that will be completed before some other point in the future (in the past of a future event). So it won't work here.

Here's an example where you could use the future perfect: Imagine a scenario where you are a shift worker who doesn't get home until 7 AM, and then you go to bed to sleep, and your friend wants to call you at 9 AM tomorrow.  You could say this:

- *If you call me tomorrow at 9 AM, I will have been asleep for only two hours*.

Here the state of being asleep happens in the past of the future event, that is the person is asleep before being called at 9 am.

Examples 1 and 2 are both are fine in my opinion. However I think you could improve on them. I don't think you need to say "coming sessions" as it's obvious from the context that you are talking about future sessions.

Perhaps try this instead:

- Will you briefly email me what the sessions are/were like after each one?

Comment: Actually, "actions that will be completed before some other point in the future" **exactly** describes what is happening in OP's example! However, as you indicate, most English speakers would not use the future perfect here, even though it is technically correct.

Comment: I was wondering what the difference is between "are" and "were" in the sentence: "Will you briefly email me what the sessions are/were like after each one?"

Comment: @JiHyunLee in the sentence you could use either ***are*** (the present tense) or ***were*** (the past tense). It really doesn't make a difference here, since you are already talking about a future event

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - hmmm, I don't think it is the same.  This sentence is rather about emailing ***after*** the sessions have occurred. The present perfect talks about actions  ***before*** a future event. I think that's why it doesn't work here.  It could also be reworded "Will you email me after each session?"

Comment: @BillyKerr Yes, the emailing (the later event) would get simple future, and the session (the earlier event) would get future perfect.